# Find and Replace random generated numbers to a single outcome

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a couple of records called `"Code": "12345678910"` I would like to change every number after "Code": to `"*****************"`

How can I change all numbers for these records called "Code": to `"*****************"`

Example Input:

```
"Code": "19991319184199999"
"Code": "29999134313199999"
"Code": "39941313199929999"
"Code": "99993113119199999"
"Code": "99913319923199999"
"Code": "21421513114141451"
```

*The numbers after `"Code":` are always random.

Example Output:

```
"Code": "*****************"
"Code": "*****************"
"Code": "*****************"
"Code": "*****************"
"Code": "*****************"
"Code": "*****************"
```

Right now Im trying to do it with find and replace, but sadly this is just a 1:1 replacement:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public Sub Testing()
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer()
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
    
    ReplaceValues SearchRange
    Debug.Print Timer() - t
End Sub
Public Function GetReplacements() As Object
    Set GetReplacements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With GetReplacements
    
.Add "Code: 9999999999", "Test"

    End With
    
End Function

Public Sub ReplaceValues(ByVal RangeToSearch As Range)
    
    Dim cellValues As Variant
    cellValues = RangeToSearch.Value2
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Replacements As Object
    Dim Replacement As Variant
    
    Set Replacements = GetReplacements()
    
    'Herhaal de array
    For i = LBound(cellValues) To UBound(cellValues)
        
        For j = LBound(cellValues, 2) To UBound(cellValues, 2)
            
            For Each Replacement In Replacements
                'Controleer of we kunnen vinden wat er bestaat, vervang daarna
                If InStr(1, cellValues(i, j), Replacement) > 0 Then
                    cellValues(i, j) = Replace(cellValues(i, j), Replacement, Replacements.Item(Replacement))
                End If
            Next
        
        Next
        
    Next
    
    RangeToSearch = cellValues
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to replace all digits with a character, eg an asterix.

```
Function replaceDigits(s As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "[0-9]" 
        .Global = True
        replaceDigits = .Replace(s, "*")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: How should I use this in my code and how can I use this for lets say 3 other options, because not everything need to change to *.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the value and then replace the "right side" to a string of `*` the same length

```
Function ChangeNumbers(strInput As String)

Dim arr() As String
Dim blnSpaceAfterDelim As Boolean

arr() = Split(strInput, ":")

blnSpaceAfterDelim = Asc(Mid(arr(1), 1, 1)) = 32

arr(1) = String(Len(Trim(arr(1))), "*")

ChangeNumbers = Join(arr, ":" & IIf(blnSpaceAfterDelim, Chr(32), vbNullString))

End Function
```

So

`ChangeNumbers("Code: 9999999999999993339999")`  gives an output of Code: ***********************

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to match all digits like

```
Function Changenumbers(x)
Dim reg As Object
Set reg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
reg.Pattern = "(\d+)"
reg.Global = True
Changenumbers = reg.Replace(x, "*****************")
End Function
```